# Can any Euclidean function be realized as a square root of positive semidefinite quadratic form?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Definiton: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $A:\mathbb R^n \to \mathcal H$ be a linear operator. A function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is called *Euclidean* if $f(x)=\|Ax\|_{\mathcal H}$ for all $x\in  \mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is, does there always exist an $n\times n$-positive semidefinite matrix $M$, such that

$$f^2(x)= x^{T}Mx,$$

for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$?

---

The converse of this should be clearly true. If we have $f^2(x)= x^{T}Mx,$ then writing $M=A^T A$ clearly gives us the Hilbert space (simply $\mathbb R^n$ and ) and operator $A$ as desired. But how about this forward direction above?

Comment: Yes. Simply define $M$ by $m_{ij}=\langle Ae_i,Ae_j\rangle_{\mathcal H}$.

Comment: @user1551 Ah... sorry for asking this stupid question.... got fooled by the Hilbert space....